# How to find the previous sibling of parent

Tags: jquery, traversal

Okay, I know this should be simple. I have a definition list (`<dl>`) that contains data definitions and data labels. I have an input in one of the data definitions so a user can define the definition.

I am then trying to get the name of the label for that definition.  In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6WJp/) the alert should prompt with "cycle_3".

```js
var myErrors = $('.myTest').prev('dt').text();
console.log(myErrors);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt> cycle_1:</dt>
  <dd> test </dd>
  <dt> cycle_2: </dt>
  <dd> test </dd>
  <dt> cycle_3: </dt>
  <dd>
    <input class="myTest" value="test" />
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('.myTest').parent().prev('dt').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$('.myTest').closest('dd').prev('dt').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm coming to this question incredibly late, it's worth pointing out that native JavaScript is perfectly capable of achieving this requirement:

```js
// here we retrieve the first element in the document which matches the
// selector passed to the document.querySelector() method (this method
// will return either the first matching element-node, or null if no
// element is found):
const input = document.querySelector('input'),

// here we navigate through the DOM from the <input> element found
// previously; we navigate to the first element (if any exists) that
// matches the selector passed to the Element.closest() method, and
// then from that <dd> element to its previous element-sibling,
// using the Node.previousElementSibling property:
      inputPreviousDT = input.closest('dd').previousElementSibling;

// here we use a template literal to interpolate the JavaScript expression
// - wrapped in the '${...}' block - into the string itself, to show the
// text-content of that element:
console.log(`The previous <dt> contains the text of: "${inputPreviousDT.textContent}"`);

// here we access the element-node, and use the classList API to
// add an orange background to further - visually - demonstrate
// that the correct <dd> element was found:
inputPreviousDT.classList.add('highlight');
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

dl {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

dt {
  font-weight: 600;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: auto;
}

dd {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: auto;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #f806;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cycle_1:</dt>
  <dd>test </dd>
  <dt>cycle_2: </dt>
  <dd>test </dd>
  <dt>cycle_3: </dt>
  <dd>
    <input class="myTest" value="test" />
  </dd>
</dl>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t1upeham/1/).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Node.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).